# jitpack - Received status code 521/401/403 from server

Tags: android, build.gradle, jitpack

My build setting is like below. And I get `Received status code 521 from server` when I build.

```
buildscript {
    // ...

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        // ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.microblink.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext{
    // ...
}
```

```
dependencies {
    // ...

    implementation('com.microblink:blinkinput:4.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it?

EDIT:

I am using private repository. So, I set

in `gradle.properties`. (the key is just an example)

```
authToken=jp_sldjflkjlzjcxlka1223
```

And in `build.gradle`.

```
...
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username authToken }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me Unauthorized(401) error.
So, I tried with this too but it gives Forbidden(403).

```
...
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username authToken }
        }
    }
}
```

The key is correct. And the project built well. It just didn't build well from yesterday.

Comment: You are all set jitpack had an issue in last hour it is all ok now

Comment: @Mkhakpaki Okay, now I have 401(Unauthorized), 403(Forbidden) error for private repository. I set all correctly but it doesn't run correctly. Why is that?

Comment: I am having the same problem since this morning but with jCenter dependencies, some of them are returning 502/403, although they are all public, I copied their URL to test them in the browser, it returns the same error code but sometimes it works and starts downloading.

Comment: https://status.gradle.com/incidents/ndfqcnmqc8n7

Comment: @HoussemNasri does `jitpick` uses `jcenter `?

Comment: as far as I know, they are completely different, the issue with jCenter is resolved so if you still get an error it's probably something else

Comment: I removed jcenter and replaced all to somethimg else like maven and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding maven jitpack to your project level gradle file you should add your jitpack token too

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { 
      url "https://jitpack.io" 
        credentials { username = project.properties['jitpackToken'] }
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.microblink.com' }
 }
}
```

You can find more info here https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/

Comment: I updated my question. I already set it correctly and it just started giving error from yesterday. @Mkhakpaki.

Comment: If the code you pasted is your real code then it is normal to have an error because you are defining your jitpack token in your gradle.properties but you dont point it there, just copy and paste my code about using jitpack token in gradle properties and it should work